# by using .htaccess file change the url parameter value

Tags: php, .htaccess

My htacess code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /demo/kingstate/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ id/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^id/([0-9]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC].
```

my url changing from http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/detail.php?id=1 to

http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/id/1 by using a htaccess file but i want a url

like http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/propperty-house-victoria.

this is first time i worked on htaccess code .

Comment: Where does "proppery-house-victoria" come from?

Comment: property is static value value where as house is a property type it may be house,apartment nd so on victoria is place...how i get this value in my url

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily use mod_rewrite to perform a lookup from `http://...?id=1` (or similar) to `http://.../some-long-name` unless you add one rule (RewriteRule line) for each number-to-name value pair.

Probably what you want to do is use PHP (and maybe SQL) to lookup the name given the number and then do a redirect. For example:

```
<?php
    $long_names = array('some-long-name','another-long-name');
    if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        header("Location: /demo/kingstate/".$long_names[$_GET['id']]);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: where i have change in htacess code or in my page??

Comment: Please explain your question again. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: above i write my htacess code which chnge my dynamic url http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/detail.php?id=1 to the static url http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/id/1 but my site is a property site so for seo purpose and according to the client requiremnt i want the property name and city of the property with id that means..http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/property-apartment-victoria-1 but i dont knw how we get the property name and place in htaccess file because my dynamic url does not have the property and place name.